# how to upgrade php my admin ? trying to update the to the latest version?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Anyone know How can I upgrade phpmyadmin to latest 4.1.14 version.  I want to use the YUM. I tried using yum upgrade it did not work.  Maybe, I need to create a repo file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using FC20 apache, php, mysql, phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you stick with the yum packaged version, you're dependent on the package managers. Whatever version they package is what you'll get. There may be third party repositories, which may provide a more updated phpMyAdmin than what you're using now, but you're still depending on a package manager to keep it updated. That's fine if that's what you want, but usually lags behind the official release schedule. The alternative is to [install it manually](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install) to your web root and update it yourself, but that's not using yum as specified in your question.

Looks like the [Fedora 20 distributed version](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/phpMyAdmin?_csrf_token=fc93e78cb2401b471df2d87a5c92da1d1f7487ec) is 3.5.8.2, which is quite a bit behind the official source.